# Redirecting /px/?q=x to /px/x/

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

We have a page that displays products depending on a query string variable `q`.

Like this:

```
http://example.com/px/?q=ninja-coffee
```

We would like to display the URL of such pages like this instead:

```
http://example.com/px/ninja-coffee/
```

So far we haven't been able to make it work, so does any of you have some ideas?

- The solution can be in `.htaccess` or in `functions.php` (we have a child theme). We are happy as long as it works
- Our page that displays products has nothing to do with normal WordPress searching. It's just a normal WordPress page that changes content based on the URL (i.e. what comes after `/px/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` add the following rule in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?px/(.*)$ px/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Based off of the default `.htaccess` generated by WordPress, it should now look like the following with your custom `RewriteRule`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Custom Rules
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?px/(.*)$ px/%1? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Clear your browser's cache and any domain that follows this structure:

```
http://example.com/px/?q=SLUG
```

Will redirect to:

```
http://example.com/px/SLUG
```

This has been verified and tested on my end using the [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).